# load content of file using ajax/jquery

Tags: jquery

I want when click on one of the links in my dive to load sub links from .php file .This works , but I want when click on "Home" link , the original links back again. This also works , but when I re click on one of these links , the sub links does not loaded any more from the .php file .

html page :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".link").click(function(){
            var value = $(this).attr("href");
            var linkName = {'href':value};
            alert(value);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'sublinks.php',
                data :linkName,
                success: function(response){
                    $('#target').html(response);
                }
            });
        }) ;
    })
</script>
.
.
.
<ul>
    <li><a href="#home" class="link">Home</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="target">
    <li><a href="#book" class="link">books</a></li>
    <li><a href="#auth" class="link">authors</a></li>
</ul>
```

sublinks.php file

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
        $name = $_POST['href'];
        $books = array('web','coocking','coding');
        $authers = array(111,222,333);

        if ($name == "#books") {
            foreach ($books as $v)
                echo "<li><a href=\"#eroom\">".$v."</li></a>";
        }
        else if ($name == "#authors") {
            foreach ($authers as $v)
                echo "<li><a href=\"#sroom\">".$v."</li></a>";
        }
        else if ($name == "#home") {
            echo "<li><a  href=\"#book\" class=\"link\">books</li></a>";
            echo "<li><a  href=\"#auth\" class=\"link\">authers</li></a>";
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your code correctly. It makes it much easier for you (and others) to follow.

Comment: And second: Please replace the PHP code with the pure HTML code from browser. Not all members are fimilar with PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$('#target').on( 'click', 'a.link', function () { 
  ..your code here
});
```

Edit: I meant change following:

```
$(".link").click(function(){
```

to

```
$('#target').on( 'click', 'a.link', function () {
```

Added:
you could also do

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.link', function() {
    .... rest of your code
});
```

Edit: This code will add a delegation so that as more `a.link` elements are added within `#target` they will have their click handler bound as well.

Comment: do you mean to do this: $('#target').on( 'click', 'a.link', function () { ... ajax code });

Comment: @calmsea yes, i meant that

Comment: But if noticed , the "home" link and the "book,auther" links are in different <ul> tags , so your solution works only if they were in the same tag